# How to crop and upload photo using cropit jquery plugin with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I currently found this photo cropping plugin called [cropit](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) . Demos are [here](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) . So what I want to do is grab the cropped photo and upload the name of the photo to the mysql database and save it to a directory using php.

So far I have this :

***HTML :***

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="image-editor">
        <div class="cropit-image-preview-container">
            <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="image-size-label">
            Resize image
        </div>
        <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
        <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

***jQUERY :***

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
        // Move cropped image data to hidden input
        var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
        $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);

        // Print HTTP request params
        var formValue = $(this).serialize();
        $('#result-data').text(formValue);

        // Prevent the form from actually submitting
        return false;
    });
```

All I need help is with the php set up code because when I crop the photo and select submit, jquery returns the serialize code, and all this code that I'm usually not familiar with appears. Here is a few characters of the serialized code jquery returns:

```
image-data=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...
```

Comment: Take a look at this awesome library -[Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/api/make)-, you won't be regret. It can be used as stand-alone library as well as Laravel package.

Comment: Can totally recommend Intervention Image. The code in the answer below didn't work (blank image) but as soon as I used Intervention it worked perfectly.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me but this Intervention Image did very well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1. Saving the base64 encoded image**

```
    <?php
    //save your data into a variable - last part is the base64 encoded image
    $encoded = "data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE";

    //decode the url, because we want to use decoded characters to use explode
    $decoded = urldecode($encoded);

    //explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
    $exp = explode(',', $decoded);

    //we just get the last element with array_pop
    $base64 = array_pop($exp);

    //decode the image and finally save it
    $data = base64_decode($base64);
    $file = 'data.png';

    //make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

**2. Getting the filename of base64 encoded image**

```
    $encoded = "data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE";
    $decoded = urldecode($encoded);
    $exp = explode(';', $decoded);
    $exp = explode(':', $exp[0]);
    $image = array_pop($exp);
    echo ($image);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I had 1 question how can i get the photo extension because it won't always be a png? The reason i ask is because I'm going to add it to the end of the file name.

Comment: The image name contains it. You can just use explode() again, just as shown in my example. Notice the given file extension does not have to match the MIME-type of the file.

Comment: How can we save jquery data in php variable?

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal you have to use ajax and set the POST or GET params

Comment: Ive noticed that even when I upload a "jpg" I still receive the encode as  "data:image/png;base64". Shouldnt it show  "data:image/jpg;base64" if it is a "jpg"?

Comment: it takes the mime type of the uploaded image. this can be different from the file extension. both formats have easily recognisable signature in the beginning so the browser can identify what kind of image it is, no matter what file extension

Answer (score -2):

I got Hosch Nok's answer to work by not decoding the encoded data.
Not calling:

```
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
```

But working directly with the `$encoded` variable.