# Cropit upload canvas image to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, canvas

I am trying to upload a cropped image with the Cropit jQuery plugin which uses the canvas in the front end. Basically trying to recreate process described here:

[How to crop and upload photo using cropit jquery plugin with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085848/how-to-crop-and-upload-photo-using-cropit-jquery-plugin-with-php)

My Node.js effort:

```
var img = //DATA RECEIVED FROM THE POST REQUEST
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(require('url').parse(img, true).path.replace(/\++/g, ' '))
var exp = decoded.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64','').split(',');
var base64 = exp.shift();
var data = base64url.decode(base64);
fs.writeFile('./public/woooo.jpg', data,function(err,done){
   if (err){
     console.log(err)
   }
})
```

The result is an image file which cannot be opened. Why? What am I doing wrong? Anyone else has managed this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(require('url').parse(img, true).path.replace(/\++/g, ' '))//base64url.decode(img);
var exp = decoded.split(',');
var base64 = exp.shift();
var data = base64url.decode(base64);
var data_c = data.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','')
var buffer = new Buffer(data_c, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('./public/woo.jpg', buffer);
```