# jQuery cropit export method return only 'data:,' string

Tags: jquery, html, crop

my html code for cropit:

```
<div id="image-cropper" style="direction: ltr">
    <div class="row margin-top-25">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="cropit-image-preview-container">
                <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-top-15">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-top-15">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <input type="file" style="display: none" class="cropit-image-input" />
            <div class="R_butt_blue choose_pic text-center">انتخاب تصویر</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my javascript code for cropit:

```
$('.choose_pic').click(function(){
     $('.cropit-image-input').click();
});

var z = $('#image-cropper').cropit({
    exportZoom: 1,
    imageBackground: true,
    imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15 // Width of background border
});
$('.send_image').click(function(){
    var h = z.cropit('export');
    $('#photo_show img').attr({ src: h });
});
```

I want to crop a image by using cropit jquery plugin, i read full document and multi [example on web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085848/how-to-crop-and-upload-photo-using-cropit-jquery-plugin-with-php), but that return only a string that contain `data:,` 
i dont know what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the `.cropit-image-preview` css class in order to set the width and the height of cropped image.

```
.cropit-image-preview {
  /* You can specify preview size in CSS */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

and also use the selector like this:

```
var z = $('#image-cropper');
z.cropit({
    exportZoom: 1,
    imageBackground: true,
    imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15 // Width of background border
});
```

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/grzveb09/