# cropit ajax upload with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crop

I'm using cropit.js for upload an image with php.

I just following this question
[How to crop and upload photo using cropit jquery plugin with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085848/how-to-crop-and-upload-photo-using-cropit-jquery-plugin-with-php)

This is my HTML code:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="formUpload">
  <div class="image-editor">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="fakeUpload" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Scegli la foto da caricare</button>
            <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" name="bannerUpload" id="bannerUpload" style="display:none;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zoomUpload" class="col-md-2">Zoom</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
            <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" id="zoomUpload">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Carica</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this the JS:

```
$('#formUpload').submit(function() {
    // Move cropped image data to hidden input
    var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
    $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);

    // Print HTTP request params
    var formValue = $(this).serialize();
    //$('#result-data').text(formValue);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url : "cpu/uploadBanner.php",
      data: formValue,
      success: function(msg){
          //$("#AjaxResult").html(msg);
          alert(msg);
      }
    })
    // Prevent the form from actually submitting
  return false;
});
```

Finally the PHP code:

```
<?php
include '../inc/config.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $encoded = $_POST['image-data'];
    //decode the url, because we want to use normal charackters to use explode
    $decoded = urldecode($encoded);
    //explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
    $exp = explode(',', $decoded);
    //we just get the last element with array_pop
    $base64 = array_pop($exp);
    //decode the image and finally save it
    $data = base64_decode($base64);
    $file = 'data.png';
    //make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo "Non dovresti essere quì!";
}
?>
```

When the form is submitted I see the new image called 'data.png' but I see all black, don't save the image correcty or what? The folder have 777 permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this PHP code:

```
<?php
include '../inc/config.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $encoded = $_POST['image-data'];
    //explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
    $exp = explode(',', $encoded);
    //decode the image and finally save it
    $data = base64_decode($exp[1]);
    $file = 'data.png';
    //make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo "Non dovresti essere quì!";
}
?>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.