# How to upload cropped image in cropit

Tags: php, jquery, image, upload, jcrop

Working on a little cropping images app. [I am using cropit for that.](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) The code looks like this:

```
  <div id="image-cropper">
      <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" />
      <script>
          $('#image-cropper').cropit();
          $('#image-cropper').cropit({ imageState: { src: { imageSrc } } });
      </script>
      <button class="export">Export</button>
      <script>
          $('.export').click(function() {
              var imageData = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
              window.open(imageData);
          });
      </script>
  </div>
```

Now I am trying to get the cropped image uploaded on the server. Using php for example. [Here was some sort of solution,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085848/how-to-crop-and-upload-photo-using-cropit-jquery-plugin-with-php) but maybe there is a simpler solution. Or at least someone could tell where I should dig more regarding php, ajax etc. for these kind of solutions.

Thanks in advance!